# Launch a fragment in my Android application from the notification bar

Tags: action, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, intentfilter

How do I start a fragment in my Android application from a notification in the notification bar?

I've tried to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16371303/956975) of creating my own action and then setting the action to the intent, but I'm unsure how to use it and what is required additionally - like adding something to the Manifest.

I've got a notification class that receives a context, a message and then an action. I then want to filter on that action to determine which fragment to launch, but I don't know how to launch a fragment as opposed to launching an activity.

Here is my Notifications.java class (incomplete):

```
public class Notifications {

    private Context mContext;

    public Notifications(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public static void notify(Context context, String message, String  action) {

        //Action you invent should include the application package as a prefix — for example: "com.example.project.SHOW_COLOR".
        action = "my.package.name.here.frag."+action;

        //Construct a user message.
        String appName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

        // Use the Notification manager to send notification
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Create a notification using android stat_notify_chat icon. 
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification, message, 0);

        //Sound, lights, vibration.
        //REMEMBER PERMISSIONS.
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

        // Create a pending intent to open the application when the notification is clicked.
        //Restart the app.
        Intent launchIntent = null;

        //Get the action and based on what the action is, launch the application displaying the appropriate fragment.
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("friend")){
            //New friend notification
            //Launch application displaying the list of friends


        }
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("article")){
            //New article has been posted
            //Launch application displaying the news feed fragment


        }
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("points")){
            //Points scored notification
            //Launch application displaying the user's profile


        }
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("redeemable")){
            //New redeemable is offered
            //Launch application displaying the list of redeemables


        }
        if (!action.equalsIgnoreCase("friend") 
                && !action.equalsIgnoreCase("article") 
                && !action.equalsIgnoreCase("points") 
                && !action.equalsIgnoreCase("redeemable")){
            //Not specific, so launch the application from scratch displaying the activity feed

            launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
        }



        if(action != null && launchIntent != null){         
            launchIntent.setAction(action);         
        }

        // Set the notification and register the pending intent to it
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appName, message, pendingIntent);

        // Trigger the notification
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this was actually pretty easy. Hopefully I can help someone else see this too.

I send an action to this `notify` function. The I add that action to my `intent` to launch an activity. In my case I open the launching activity, because all the fragments are loaded from within that activity based on what the user does. So I set the action using `setAction` and the I use that action in the activity as below.

My `Notifications.java` class changed to this:

```
public static void notify(Context context, String message, String  action) {

    action = action.toUpperCase();

    // Create a pending intent to open the the application when the notification is clicked.
    //Restart the app.
    Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());

    if(action != null && launchIntent != null){         
        launchIntent.setAction(action);         
    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, -1, launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();  
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 

    // Set the notification and register the pending intent to it
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appName, message, pendingIntent);

    // Trigger the notification
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

And then in my `activity` from where I load the fragments, I get the action and filter it:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

try{
    String action = intent.getAction().toUpperCase();

    if(action != null){
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_action_friend))){
                goFrag(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FRAG_A_INT));
            }
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_action_article))){
                goFrag(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FRAG_B_INT));
            }
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_action_points))){
                goFrag(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FRAG_C_INT));
            }
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_action_redeemable))){
                goFrag(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FRAG_D_INT));
            }
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_action_dance))){
                goFrag(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.FRAG_E_INT));
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "Intent was null");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Problem consuming action from intent", e);              
    }
```

In my `goFrag` function I replace the fragment if the required fragment is still in memory (meaning the user was there earlier and it hasn't been destroyed yet), or I create a new fragment required.

Comment: How to check fragment is in memory??

Comment: String[] frag_tags = { "fragment1", "fragment2", "fragment3"};
Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(frag_tags[fragNumber]);
  if (frag != null) {
   Log.d(TAG, "Frag is in memory: " + String.valueOf(fragNumber));
   transaction.replace(R.id.lin_main_container, frag, frag_tags[fragNumber]);
  } else {
   Log.d(TAG, "Recreating frag: " + String.valueOf(fragNumber));
}

Comment: why is my action is null?

Comment: is the second part of the code written in `OnCreate` or `NewIntent` ? How to take care of that when the activity is already running or when it is not.

Comment: @Nezam - put it in onCreate. I used it in a function which I called from the function where I set up the UI, which I call from onCreate after I've established a few variables.

Comment: consider using tags for your fragments'it's way easier