# how to open particular fragment when notification is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications

I have a notification in notification bar and i have 3 fragments in one of my activity. i want when i click the notification it will open particular fragment, Like what facebook notification do. I tried to search it on google n everywhere else but didnot match what i need.
Example: i have 3 fragments 
1 - for redeem value.
2 - for recharge.
3 - for anything.

Now if i get notification from Admin Panel like you can redeem your value, then that notification will open that particular fragment. If i get notification to recharge then it will open that particular fragment like this i want all working.

Hope you clear, if not then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this link for open notification in fragment you should use Pending Intent for it and set your fragment with name and open it with pending intent, [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378897/launch-a-fragment-in-my-android-application-from-the-notification-bar)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608627/how-to-open-fragment-page-when-pressed-a-notification-in-android)

Comment: Thanks Alka, I have already gone through with this link and it show exception then I tried other codes too which i found on Google and here but didnot match with my issue actually.

Comment: Gone through Thanks BTW.

Comment: @Programmer welcome if it is help to u..dnt foget to up a vote.