# reset action passed via notification once used in onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications, oncreate

I am able to set an action when a notification is created. Once user clicks on it, application is getting opened and I was able to check the action value. I referred below link

[Android opening specific tab fragment on notification click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370422/android-opening-specific-tab-fragment-on-notification-click)

Using `setAction()` I am setting a action and on click on notification , in activity `onCreate()` I am able to get the value.

My problem is every time `onCreate()` is called I am getting the value when `onCreate()` is called (such as rotation). 
Is there a way to clear the action once I captured in `onCreate()`, I want `getActivity().getAction()` should give value only when the app is re invoked by clicking notification.

Comment: what is that getActivity() call? it is not an api call...

Comment: I used getIntent().getAction().equals(ACTION) where ACTION is set while creating the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `Activity.setIntent(new Intent())` to set a blank intent or use `Activity.getIntent().setAction(null)` to set a blank action after you received the action.